# How To implement Facebook friends module in Database?

Tags: java, database, facebook, graph, social-networking

I am developing a facebook type application for my institute.

and I am stuck at the friends module. i.e. How to know if the particular users are one's friends.

I googled a lot but didn't get any satisfactory answers.
What I got is : there will be many friends of a person and implementing users and their friends in seperate table will only increase redundancy and large DB size.

I thought of using a graph with vertices as users and edges as connection .

But how to implement something like that in db.

Or How Facebook handles such huge amount of relationships?

Comment: I'm pretty sure facebook uses NoSQL solutions, because relational databases would be too bloated for the data they have. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL

Comment: thanks seanizer........ after searching and resding about noSql, I got to know Cassandra that's perfect for my application. I hope so:-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would have a dedicated table for it:

You could have a table with just two columns: userID and friendID

Since the relationships between users in the db will be many-to-many, normalizing it requires a link table which breaks it into many-to-one-to-many

http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/intro-to-normalization.html#03

Comment: Well I have thought about this approach earlier... but it only leads to more data , more headaches and more programming.

Comment: @Ashutosh This is the best solution. All others would bring even more headache and programming. Many to many is never easy to work with.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problems are usually solved by using a different type of database. For a social network, a [graph database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_database) should make sense, as nodes and relationships are first class citizens in it. There's a [social network example](http://components.neo4j.org/neo4j-examples/1.2-SNAPSHOT/social-network.html) for the [Neo4j](http://neo4j.org/) graph database, the full source code of the example is included in the standard dowload package. I've also written a [blog post](http://blog.neo4j.org/2009/09/social-networks-in-database-using-graph.html) on this theme, with another example as starting point.